# Vue-ChartJS - Circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-chartjs

i'm using *Vue-Chartjs* lib, and i'm trying to make a line chart. Well, i have done it with this code below, it works! The graph is drawed. But when i change the value of any variable inside my `Vue Data` (Like this `test` input, in the example.). It evals this error in console. I think it is because of VueChartJS, because if i remove the graph, everything works well.

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

**line.js**

```
import {Line, mixins} from 'vue-chartjs'
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

export default {
   extends: Line,
   mixins: [reactiveProp],
   props: ['options'],
   mounted() {
      this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
   }
}
```

**dashboard.vue**

```
<line-chart :chart-data="dataCollection" :height="100"></line-chart>
 <input v-model="test">

   import LineChart from './line-chart.js';
   export default {
      components: {LineChart},
      data: () => ({ 
         dataCollection:  {},
         test: "some input" 
      }),
      created () { 
         this.dataCollection =  {
                  "labels": ["0:00", "1:00", "2:00", "3:00", "4:00", "5:00"],
                  "datasets": [{
                     "label": "Test",
                     "backgroundColor": "#00CC6A",
                     "borderColor": "#00CC6A",
                     "data": [0, 23, 51.75, 27, 34, 12]
                  }]
               }
        }
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!! =)

Comment: There's a typo in `this.dataCollection: {` (it should be `this.dataCollection = {`).

Comment: I can't reproduce the error in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7yoxmr4wk6)

Comment: @tony19 i spend 2 days to reproduce the error... i was putting the `{{dataCollection}}` to see my data... And this reproduce the error in console... My question now is: Why? D= ... I'm very confused.
here is a updated codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/4rwqj8z9nx

Answer (score 4):

I guess the problem according to your sandbox, is that you are trying to output the datacollection in the template.

If the chart.js data object containing a circular structure, (referencing the object somewhere in the childobject), this can lead to the error.

Because if you print out the object in your vue template, vue uses JSON.stringify() in the background. Which can not resolve circular structures.

Comment: this is right, the problem is the `_meta` property in `datasets`, see https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/396